# Access 2003 subform to RecordsetClone resets subform from Main Form

Tags: ms-access, subforms

I am at odds with Access VBA at the moment. I have an Invoicing program I designed that uses a form with several subforms to generate a new order. One of the subforms is for collecting quantity of items ordered, number back ordered, and the item name. When an order is completed, the tables behind the form will update the main table with item cost, any discounts the selected client may receive, etc. My problem is that I need to (sometimes, and on demand) have a subtotal of the current order, and usually while the order is still being generated. What I thought to do is to generate a temporary table with all the items, quantities, discounts applied and calculate the current subtotal from that table. I can generate the temporary table with all the information I need, but then the subform on the main invoice form disappears - well, it reverts back to an empty subform, to be more accurate.

1st Question: Why is does the subform "reset"?

2nd Question: Should I be using this method for displaying the current subtotal?

I have tried DSUM And DLOOKUP on the subform and that simply didn't work at all. I kept getting #NAME? Or #ERROR returned and gave up.

Comment: A couple of questions/points: (a) your 'subject' mentions RecordsetClone, yet no mention in details; (b) are your subforms bound to temp tables now?; (c) you mention 'several subforms', but only one disappears?; (d) can you share the code you have used? If your subforms are bound, then you can easily add code that will update a subtotal anytime a change/insert/delete occurs.

Comment: Thanks, Wayne!  Sorry about not being clear.  a) The temporary table is generated from the RecordsetClone.  After it's generated (which is launced from a control) the subform "resets".  b) The subforms are not bound to the tables. c) Yes, only the one subform disappears.  The others are bound to other tables and remain d) I could share the code, but I have since found a way to use DLookUp to get the line totals I need but the =SUM for the subform's sub total (CumSum) is throwing #ERROR.  I have tried all I can think of here to no avail.  Thanks again!

Comment: What do you have in the 'Record Source' property of the subform? How is that data populated / changed (rs.Addnew for the clone?) Is the control used for the subtotal part of the row or is it an unbound control? Can't you just spin thru the rsclone and sum?

Comment: Thanks again, Wayne.  I'm going to give that a try today.  I know this can be done, I'm just not an advanced programmer and have no good resource near at hand so I tend to flounder.  I'll report back later.

Comment: I have found one problem.  I was mistaken in my first reply.  The subform is bound to the main Invoice table and I'd rather have a temp table that is the information that I call into and the calculated fields of the Subform, not the bound table. The Invoice table doesn't have all the discount and adjusted cost data that I have on the subform. The Invoice table will only receive the end calculated cost per item.  What I need is the current order subtotalled and displayed on the order entry form. When I add a =sum(...calculation...) it adds the quantities and multiplies by the FIRST value only.

Comment: Is this a multi-user app? If so, is it a FE/BE setup, and does each user have their own copy of the front-end? Since your subform is bound to the main table, I'm guessing you filter the records to show just one order at a time? You also say '...Invoice tabl edoesn't have all the ...' which must mean you have other tables for that data? Please show the full syntax of your '=sum(...' and tell where you have placed that - in a textbox or a query field, or ... Yes, you can create a temp table, but it may not be necessary. If you edit data you need to worry about integrity if something happens.

Comment: Yes, @WayneGDunn, I have gotten far along without using the temporary table and have started a new question with far more detail than I included in this question. Thank you so much for your time on this, but I felt my current question is far enough removed from this question that it warranted starting a new thread. You have truly been very helpful!